# How to limit the "depth" of a folder-tree a filter returns in HP ALM?

Tags: testing, filter, alm, hp-quality-center

I am trying to build some simple graphs in HP ALM to follow the advancement of test case statuses. 
We have a classic tree structure of test cases sorted in folders like

```
Root
-Level 1
--Level 2
---Level 3
---Level 3
---Level 3
--Level 2
---Level 3
-Level 1
--Level 2
---Level 3
----Level 4
```

etc

I figured the best way to get a filter that counts the test cases and groups them by their "status" is to filter by "Subject". I point each graph's filter to Level 1 and it works, but the filter actually provides a column for every level of the tree. What i want it to do is to only generate columns for Level 2 and combine all the remaining sub-levels into a single result.

Is there a way to force such a thing?

Comment: You can very well do it using BFS traversal. Would you mind posting the code that you developed so far? Are you doing this using REST API or OTA?

Comment: Hello, i am using the standard ALM interface, the goal is to build dashbaords directly in ALM, not use the data outside...Here's 1 filter, for example: Filter: Subject[^Subject\02_TNR\Produit - Cahier de recette\99-JASPER^]

Comment: If you want to query test designs or folders with a maximum hierarchy level, you can use the `hierarchical-path` attribute. Test designs (`/tests/`) have a parent folder (`/test-folders/`). These test folders have a `hierarchical-path` attribute. This attribute indicates the hierarchy level when you divide it by 3 (default size). E.g. if `hierarchical-path = AAAAAPAAA` it means it's a top-level folder (the `Subject` folder (root) has `hierarchical-path = <6 letters>`). 
The filter feature supports regular expressions. You can specify a maximum size for `hierarchical-path`.